# EACESS permission denied when installing global npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, permissions

When I try to install something (gulp, sass, webpack, etc.) *globally* with `sudo npm install packagename -g` I always get these errors:

> node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib'
>
> gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/erik/.node-gyp/11.11.0"
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'

And a whole lot more similar errors.

I have tried fixing disk permissions with Disk Repair. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled Node. I have tried other answers on stack overflow, such as:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

and

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

but this has not helped.

How do I fix the permissions so that I can install global npm packages again?

I'm running OS X Mojave with Node 11.11.0

Comment: For me, i just wanted to make it work an addet the `--unsafe-perm`  option, for example when installing sqlite3 `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g sqlite3`. Then it worked, but I don't know the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. Still not sure why I get so many errors when installing globally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled with this a bit as well and eventually found that you need to set the global package installation location to a folder that you have permissions for.

`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'` 
then export the path 
`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

all this information can be found on the npm documentation site

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 3):

A rule of thumb, as I have learned is to never use `npm install` with sudo! This created items with `root` as owner as opposed to you as owner.

Comment: But how do you install globally then?